# Can't catch exception thrown by JWT.

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm making a small web api with asp.net core 2.0. I'm using JWT to protect my api end-points.

This is the jwt middleware I'm using [this jwt bearer authentication](https://github.com/aspnet/Security)

This is my **Startup.cs** file:

```
public class Startup
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///     Instance stores configuration of application.
        /// </summary>
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        ///     Callback which is fired when application starts.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="env"></param>
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services"></param>
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add entity framework to services collection.
            var sqlConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnectionString");
            services.AddDbContext<RelationalDatabaseContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly(nameof(Main))));

            // Injections configuration.
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddScoped<DbContext, RelationalDatabaseContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IEncryptionService, EncryptionService>();
            services.AddScoped<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();
            services.AddScoped<ITimeService, TimeService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            // Requirement handler.
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, SolidAccountRequirementHandler>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleRequirementHandler>();

            // Load jwt configuration from setting files.
            services.Configure<JwtConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtConfiguration)));
            services.Configure<ApplicationSetting>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationSetting)));

            // Build a service provider.
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var jwtBearerSettings = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<JwtConfiguration>>().Value;

            // Cors configuration.
            var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();

            // Add cors configuration to service configuration.
            services.AddCors(options => { options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", corsBuilder.Build()); });
            services.AddOptions();

            // This can be removed after https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/371
            var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                // You also need to update /wwwroot/app/scripts/app.js
                o.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
                o.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new JwtBearerValidator());
               o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = jwtBearerSettings.Audience,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtBearerSettings.Issuer,
                    IssuerSigningKey = jwtBearerSettings.SigningKey
                };
            });


            #region Mvc builder

            // Construct mvc options.
            services.AddMvc(mvcOptions =>
            {
                mvcOptions.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter());
                ////only allow authenticated users
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

#if !ALLOW_ANONYMOUS
                    .AddRequirements(new SolidAccountRequirement())
#endif
                    .Build();

                mvcOptions.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

            })
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });

#endregion
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        /// <param name="env"></param>
        /// <param name="loggerFactory"></param>
        /// <param name="serviceProvider"></param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
            IHostingEnvironment env,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Enable logging.
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            // Use JWT Bearer authentication in the system.
            app.UseAuthentication();

            // Enable cors.
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");

            // Enable MVC features.
            app.UseMvc();
        }

#endregion
    }
```

By using this line of code :

```
mvcOptions.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter());
```

I can catch exception thrown by ASP.Net MVC controllers, attributes, ...
But I can't catch exception thrown by JWT.

```
authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                // You also need to update /wwwroot/app/scripts/app.js
                o.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
                o.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new JwtBearerValidator());
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = jwtBearerSettings.Audience,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtBearerSettings.Issuer,
                    IssuerSigningKey = jwtBearerSettings.SigningKey
                };

            });
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

Comment: Look at the exception handling middleware that's in the new project templates. UseExceptionHandler. There's also an AuthenticationFailed Event off of the jwt options you can hook.

Comment: I tried that but only able to catch MVC Exception. I know AuthenticationFailed , but I wonder whether there is anyway to catch exception globally or not.

Comment: Where did you put it? It has to go before UseAuthentication. I guess you can't use the reexecute version as you'd hit the same exception again, you'd need to use one of the direct response overloads.

Comment: What exceptions are you looking to catch, specifically? Do you want to know when the token fails validation, for example?

Comment: Yes, I need to catch the exception thrown by ISecurityTokenValidator.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding global exception handling for such errors using **global exceptions handling** approach. have a look at package for exception handling as a convention in `ASP.NET Core` request pipeline - [JosephWoodward/GlobalExceptionHandlerDotNet](https://github.com/JosephWoodward/GlobalExceptionHandlerDotNet)

Comment: As the description said, I think its only for controller exceptions logging. I don't think it will work with Jwt bearer middleware

Comment: Test first! TDD :)

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. It can only catch exception thrown inside controllers. :'(